# Installing Zookeeper on offline openshift

Tags: docker, openshift, apache-zookeeper

I've an Openshift Origin cluster running offline on 3 Centos 7 vm. It's working fine, I've a registry where I push my images like this :

```
docker login -u <username> -e <any_email_address> -p <token_value> <registry_ip>:<port>
```

Login is successful, then :

```
oc tag <image-id> <docker-registry-IP>:<port>/<project-name>/<image>
```

So, for nginx for example :

```
oc tag 49011ce3b713 172.30.222.111:5000/test/nginx
```

Then I push it to the internal registry :

```
docker push 172.30.222.111:5000/test/nginx
```

And finaly :

```
oc new-app nginx --name="nginx"
```

With nginx, everything is working fine, now my problem :

I'm actually wanting to put Zookeeper on it, so : I do the same steps than above, I also install "jboss/base-jdk:7" which is a dependancy of Zookeeper, problem is :

```
docker push 172.30.222.111:5000/test/jboss/base-jdk:7
```

Giving :

```
[root@master 994089]# docker push 172.30.222.111:5000/test/jboss/base-jdk:7
The push refers to a repository [172.30.222.111:5000/test/jboss/base-jdk]
c4c6a9114a05: Layer already exists
3bf2c105669b: Layer already exists
85c6e373d858: Layer already exists
dc1e2dcdc7b6: Layer already exists
Received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error
```

The problem seems to be the "/" here jboss**/**base-jdk:7

I also tried to push just like this :

```
docker push 172.30.222.111:5000/test/base-jdk:7
```

This is working , but Zookeeper is looking for exactly "jboss/base-jdk:7", and not just "base-jdk:7"

Finally, I'm blocked here, when trying this command : `oc new-app zookeeper --name="zookeeper" --loglevel=8 --insecure-registry  --allow-missing-images`

```
I0628 14:31:54.009713   53407 dockerimagelookup.go:92] checking local Docker daemon for "jboss/base-jdk:7"
I0628 14:31:54.030546   53407 dockerimagelookup.go:380] partial match on "172.30.222.111:5000/test/base-jdk:7" with 0.375000
I0628 14:31:54.030571   53407 dockerimagelookup.go:346] exact match on "jboss/base-jdk:7"
I0628 14:31:54.030578   53407 dockerimagelookup.go:107] Found local docker image match "172.30.222.111:5000/test/base-jdk:7" with score 0.375000
I0628 14:31:54.030589   53407 dockerimagelookup.go:107] Found local docker image match "jboss/base-jdk:7" with score 0.000000
I0628 14:31:54.032799   53407 componentresolvers.go:59] Error from resolver: [can't look up Docker image "jboss/base-jdk:7": Internal error occurred: Get http://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.253.158.90:53: no such host]
I0628 14:31:54.032831   53407 dockerimagelookup.go:169] Added missing image match for jboss/base-jdk:7
F0628 14:31:54.032882   53407 helpers.go:110] error: can't look up Docker image "jboss/base-jdk:7": Internal error occurred: Get http://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.253.158.90:53: no such host
```

We can see that 172.30.222.111:5000/test/base-jdk:7 is found but it's not exactly what the command is looking for so it doesn't use it...

So, if you have any idea how to solve this ! :)

Comment: Did you mean ``docker push`` rather than ``oc push``? There is no ``oc push`` command.

Comment: Yes sorry, edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by upgrading to Openshift 1.5.1, previous was 1.3.1.